# ViewPager set Fragment without adapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter

I have viewpager , bottomnavigation and Fab . While I am swiping it is changing fragments position in viewpager with framents array in Adapter . I want to set differennt fragment to ViewPager once I clicked Fab . How can I do this ? Can I set fragment to viewpager without adapter ?